# Trying to figure out why a websites cert is coming back as another cert that I have

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I am trying to setup https for a domain. I created the elastic beanstalk and uploaded my app just fine.

I then purchased the new domain and added an alias to the route 53 hosted zone.
[image]

I then created a cert for both [the domain].com and *.[the domain].com.
[image]

I then copied the CNAME values of that cert into the hosted zone for that domain

I then changed the eb config to load balanced in capacity and edited the load balancer configuration to terminate https using the certificate I'd just created
[image]

So now I can go to the original eb generated url and it's okay with https however when I try going to the new domain that I purchased it reads as insecure.
[image]

What's weird is that the cert that's displaying for the domain I just purchased is reading as a cert for another domain I own.

Comment: Does your Webserver still try to answer https request as if they are coming from the old domain or does your server only understand http anyway?? Note that e.g. route53 is irrelevant here because it was only needed for the certificate validation, it has no influence over the "runtime" behavior. Do you see the actual request showing up on the expected server / instance?

Comment: @luk2302 I believe that's why the cert is added to the load balancer correct?

Comment: *I* don't know if your load balancer is ever actually used... if your dns still points to your Webserver itself which is still set up to use your old domain and your own certificate then the error message would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DNS server may still be pointing to an old IP.  Check your domain name with `dig` or `nslookup`.  You may need to wait for up to 48 hours for DNS routing to straighten out.